# Parent Child Relation Ship Upto Infinite level

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to build infinite level parent and child relationship.

In my requirement I am having parent libraries, in each parent library i am having list of publications related to that particular library and child libraries. In each child library gain we have publications associated with it and child libraries.... this process continues..

Can any one provide a sample code to achieve this .

Comment: Well, if your object knows it's parent and children, where is the Problem? It's a simple 1:n relationship for children and 1:1 for parent (root wont have any parent).

Comment: How to store this information in a class, logic, how to implement this.